# Collection of short horror stories with a spider woman?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a collection of short horror stories.

One story had a journalist trying hard to get an interview with a famous woman. She agreed to meet him at an address at night. The address turned out to be a dark alley way he started asking her questions but she was giving him strange answers. She had been standing in the dark shadows and suddenly from the weird answers the journalist knew he had been set up. She stepped into the light. As she was changing into a huge spider or insect she told him the truth of how she became this because she knew he wouldn't get the chance to tell anyone.

I read this collection in early 2000s and I think the collection may have had a submission by Stephen king and or Dean Koontz.

Comment: This *may* be a story by Robert Bloch -- any chance it could be "The Model"? See www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62359 for collections including it.

Comment: In *The Model* the woman doesn't turn into a spider. It's a [vagina dentata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagina_dentata) story.